# Transfer my iPad to different user account on same computer?

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization

I'm trying to transfer ownership of my iPad to a different user account on a different computer. Obviously this is basically the same thing as transferring it to a new computer.

I don't want to lose all my apps and have to remember what I had installed. I thought I might be able to make a hard backup and move it over to the other account, and wipe and restore the iPad on there, but the backup seems to persist the information about which user account / iTunes combination owns it.

Is it possible at all to move my iPad onto a new computer without endless pain and manual work?

There's no option to 'transfer purchases' when I try to sync the iPad. Both are using the same Apple ID on the iTunes store.

Comment: Ultimately I'm just trying to do a one-off migration without having to _wipe_ my iPad and simply try to remember what apps I had installed. Surely this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Why not tether the iPad to iCloud, then it doesn't need a computer at all? If you do that and turn on backups, you can then set it to manage music (or media, if you do videos too) manually, and then you can drag stuff on and off from either computer, and none of your purchases will be lost.

When you plug into the new computer it might ask you to authorise your account but you can have up to five devices or something so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though I'd rather not store my data on iCloud, nor have to pay for extra storage when it's above the free level.

Comment: Understand about paying for extra - although your entire iPad backup will come to around 500mb - so the space shouldn't be an issue, but curious as to why you don't like iCloud?